# calling method within class in python

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to call method within a class; that call is the last line below, **self.z()**

```
class Wait:
    def __init__(self,a):
            self.a = a
    def countdown(self,a):
       for remaining in range(self.a, 0, -1):
          sys.stdout.write("\r")
          sys.stdout.write("{:2d} seconds remaining.".format(remaining))
          sys.stdout.flush()
          time.sleep(1)
       sys.stdout.write("\rWait Complete!            \n")
    def z(self):
       self.countdown(100)
    self.z()
```

However, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./countdown.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Wait:
  File "./countdown.py", line 18, in Wait
    self.z()
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

How can I call `countdown` from another method within this class ?

Comment: Are you wanting to fire `self.z()` immediately upon object creation?

Comment: `self.z()` that works only from within an instance method of the class. what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Does this really need to be a class at all? What's wrong with having `countdown` as a standalone function?

Comment: There is already bunch of code where a class already exists, say class ABC. Other methods in this class ABC currently uses time.sleep where I have to, at times, wait for 100 seconds. Instead of using time.sleep I want to use method countdown which can be used by other methods in this class ABC. I do not want to create a separate class for just countdown. To summarize, how do I make use of method countdown within a class for other methods?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with letting other methods use the countdown method, though.

Comment: Let's say I have other method called as temp and instead of time.sleep, I want to make use of countdown. How do I do it?

Comment: You call `self.countdown(some_number)`, exactly as you have done. There's nothing wrong with `countdown` in your code; the problem is that you're calling `z()` in a place where you're not allowed to. Presumably in your real code, this won't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that **self** is not defined in the class body; **self** is a parameter of each of the methods, but you're not inside any method at that point.  I think you might be trying to test this with a 100-second countdown, which means that you need that bottom code in your main program:

```
class Wait:
    def __init__(self,a):
          self.a = a
    def countdown(self,a):
       for remaining in range(self.a, 0, -1):
          sys.stdout.write("\r")
          sys.stdout.write("{0:2d} seconds remaining.".format(remaining))
          sys.stdout.flush()
          time.sleep(1)
       sys.stdout.write("\rWait Complete!            \n")
    def z(self):
       self.countdown(100)

ticker = Wait(10)
ticker.z()
```

Note that your code ignores the **100** value sent in from **z**, instead using the timer value set at creation.  Also note that I've corrected your formatted output statement.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted. As mentioned earlier, I just do not want to use another class for countdown/wait. I want to use countdown method in the same class what I have currently say class ABC so that I can use it within other methods of class ABC. Let's say, def z wants to execute a cli "abcd" and wants to wait for 100 sec.

Comment: Then please clarify your question, perhaps showing a failed attempt with class ABC.  Your posting gives all of the methods as being within **Wait**, and my answer preserves that.  Your error is in placing active code in the body of a *Class*, and in trying to use a variable that's not defined at that level.

Comment: Also, note that I *did* answer your given question: your countdown method is, indeed, callable from within the class.  Your call of **z** is illegal, but having **z** invoke **countdown** is already correct.

Comment: I apologize, my bad for not being clear. Let's say, I have same set of code as you have mentioned above, instead, the name of the class is class ABC. Now, I have 2 methods here countdown and z. No change in the code of countdown. The code for method z is as follows:
    def z(self):
          print("before execution of cli")
          self.countdown(100)
          print("Now executing cli abcd")

Comment: What about it?  All you've done here is to change the name of the class and add two print statements to **z**.  This does not affect the answer I gave: **z** can easily call **countdown**, and any object of **ABC** can invoke its **z** method.

Comment: Alright, looks like I need to use Wait class and create an object to use the countdown method.

Comment: Yes -- that's part of the definition of a Class, part of the structure of object-oriented programming: a class method is a property of an object (instance) of the class.